# Need help parsing XML with retrofit

Tags: android, xml

I´ve been using JSON converter in retrofit for my app but this one response is coming as an XML which I have never used before. Can someone please help me set up the structure of the class to parse this XML?. This is what I´ve done so far

https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=bitcoin&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en

```
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
public class News @JvmOverloads constructor (
    @field:ElementList(name = "item", required = false)
    @Path("channel")
    var item: ArrayList<Item1>
)

@Root (name="item", strict = false) public class Item1 {
    @Element(name = "title", required = false)
    private val title: String? = null
    @Element(name = "link", required = false)
    private val link: String? = null
    @Element(name = "pubDate", required = false)
    private val pubDate: String? = null
    @Element(name = "description", required = false)
    private val description: String? = null
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser

Comment: This doesn´t really answer the question regarding retrofit, does it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an XML converter for retrofit located at these coordinates

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:latest.version'
```

You just install it the same way you would install a JSON converter.

```
        Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("url")
                .addConverterFactory(
           SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(
                  new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy())  
             )
```

Here is a sample response file generated from https://jsonformatter.org/xml-to-kotlin using the link you posted

```
data class RSS (
    val channel: Channel,

    @Json(name = "_xmlns:media")
    val xmlnsMedia: String,

    @Json(name = "_version")
    val version: String
)

data class Channel (
    val generator: String,
    val title: String,
    val link: String,
    val language: String,
    val webMaster: String,
    val copyright: String,
    val lastBuildDate: String,
    val description: String,
    val item: List<Item>
)

data class Item (
    val title: String,
    val link: String,
    val guid: GUID,
    val pubDate: String,
    val description: String,
    val source: Source
)

data class GUID (
    @Json(name = "_isPermaLink")
    val isPermaLink: String,

    @Json(name = "__text")
    val text: String
)

data class Source (
    @Json(name = "_url")
    val url: String,

    @Json(name = "__text")
    val text: String
)
```

Comment: I have actually done this already. My problem is that I don´t know how to write the class

Comment: @OscarBerggren I have edited the answer to add a sample Kotlin response generated from https://jsonformatter.org/xml-to-kotlin. You can easily generate data classes these days from complex JSON and XML structures using free websites and tools.

Comment: Thank you but it still does not work. I get the error "Constructor not matched for class"

Comment: I think I can solve it. Instead of trying to create an XML right away I found a way to return the response as a string in retrofit and from there convert it to a class